# Euler's Method question

Tags: numerical-methods

I have this differential equation $y'=\frac{y(\sin t)}{t}$, $y(0)=2$, and $h=\frac{1}{4}$.
The first set of values, the inital, are $(0,2)$.
For the next iteration would it be $y_1=2+(\frac{1}{4})\left(\frac{2\cdot\sin(0)}{0}\right)$? I know you can't divide by zero, so what would should I do in this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that $$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1. $$

Comment: Great, I didn't think of that, thanks!

Comment: @Alti: You are welcome.